# window.onresize not working when call at different js files in a same html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have used the window.reize function twice in a same file from different server , but window.resize function is not working. Only one code get working. I have an HTML code like below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/workspace/appldp_27_03_17/show-ads.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://appldp.com/show-ads.js"></script>
```

I run the above html file in my localhost directory.
Also the show-ads.js file has a code in it

```
function somethingCalledFunction(currentURL){
  window.onresize = function(event) {
    console.log(currentURL);
  }
}
```

It only console the URL from the appldp.com server why it is like that.

Comment: Hmm... If you'll set `A` to a variable `a`, and then you'd set `B` to the same variable, what do think, which value you will get?

Comment: What u mean by A , a , B , b ?

Comment: is the command somethingCalledFunction(); ever actually performed? Also, try putting an alert("a"); above the function to ensure that to JavaScript file is properly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

> It only console the URL from the appldp.com server why it is like that.

As @Teemu pointed out, the problem is that your library is loaded twice. So, the same file in memory twice. To avoid this, it overwrites the previous one and call the function you edited in the post.